# Which IDE can i use to create a mobile application in KendoUI?

Tags: kendo-mobile

I checked AppBuilder in Telerik, it allows us to check the development instantly in mobile. Is there any IDE to use like that for developing mobile app in Kendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some  research from my side, Sublime Text 2 and Visual studio can be used to develop Kendo mobile application with help of Command Line Interface(CLI).

http://www.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder#IDEchoices

http://www.telerik.com/blogs/the-telerik-platform-now-with-100-more-sublime-text